# Need help on multilevel nested table

Tags: apex, soql, pageblocktable, pageblocksection

I am trying to display 2 level deep relation from parent to grandchild. Parent is **order**, child is **order lines** and grandchild is **shipment lines**.

*Order-->Orderlines-->Shipmentlines*

I am able to display All **orderlines** from **orders**. But I'm unable to correctly display **shipment lines** for every **orderlines**. I get repeated shipment lines for unrelated order lines.

```
public class OrderTrackingList{
public OrderTrackingList(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

}

public list<wrapgroupwise> singlegroup;
public List<wrapgroupwise> getStartHere(){
singlegroup= new List<wrapgroupwise>();
List<order_lines__c> temol= [SELECT Id, name,calculated_estimated_delivery_date__c,order_number__c,status__c,planned_ship_date__c,material_name__c,material_no__c, quantity_ordered__c, material_group__c,(SELECT Id,Name,Order_Number__c,Actual_Delivery_Date__c, estimated_delivery_date__c,Shipment_Number__r.name, Shipment_Number__r.carrrier_name__c, Shipment_Number__r.carrier_website__c,Shipment_Number__r.tracking_number__c,quantity_shipped__c, material_group__c,order_lines__c  From shipment_lines__r ) From order_lines__c where number_of_order_lines__c=:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];

List<orders__c> tempacc=[SELECT Orders__c,CreatedBy.FirstName,CreatedDate, number_of_line_items__c, CurrencyIsoCode,account__r.name,contract__r.ContractNumber,customer_order_number__c,invoices__c,my_view__c,order_acknowlegment__c,order_date__c,order_value__c, order_no__c, requested_delivery_date__c,shipments__c,Id,Name,
                             (SELECT Id, name,calculated_estimated_delivery_date__c,order_number__c,status__c,planned_ship_date__c,material_name__c,material_no__c, quantity_ordered__c, material_group__c From Order_Lines__r),

                             (SELECT invoices__r.invoice_no__c, CurrencyIsoCode,account__c,due_date__c,invoice_date__c,material_group__c,material_name__c,material_number__c,orders__c, order_lines__c, product_family__c,product_type__c,Id,Name,quantity__c, invoices__r.Name, invoices__r.status__c, invoices__r.invoice_value__c , invoices__r.due_date__c, invoices__r.number_of_days_past_due__c, invoices__r.invoice_date__c From Invoice_Lines__r)
                              FROM orders__c where id=:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
 system.debug('-----tempacc-------'+tempacc);

 for(Integer i=0; i<tempacc.size() ; i++){
    List <order_lines__c> tempOrderLines = tempacc[i].order_lines__r;
    List <shipment_lines__c> tempShipmentLines = [SELECT Id,Name,Order_Number__c,Actual_Delivery_Date__c, estimated_delivery_date__c,Shipment_Number__r.name, Shipment_Number__r.carrrier_name__c, Shipment_Number__r.carrier_website__c,Shipment_Number__r.tracking_number__c,quantity_shipped__c, material_group__c,order_lines__c  From shipment_lines__c Where order_lines__c IN: tempacc[i].tempOrderLines];
    List <invoice_lines__c> tempInvoiceLines = tempacc[i].Invoice_Lines__r;

     if(tempOrderLines.size()==0 ){/*&& tempShipmentLines.size()==0 && tempInvoiceLines.size()==0*/
              singlegroup.add(new wrapgroupwise(tempacc[i],null,null,null)); 
        }
    else{

      if(tempShipmentLines.size()==0)
        {
          if(tempOrderLines[i].status__c=='Open')
           {
               tempOrderLines[i].calculated_estimated_delivery_date__c=tempOrderLines[i].planned_ship_date__c;
           }

        singlegroup.add(new wrapgroupwise(tempacc[i],tempOrderLines,null,null)); 

        }//if condition for tempShipmentLines size check    
      else
      {
     //Estimated Delivery Date done

       if(tempOrderLines[i].status__c=='Open')
       {
           tempOrderLines[i].calculated_estimated_delivery_date__c=tempOrderLines[i].planned_ship_date__c;
       }
       if(tempOrderLines[i].status__c=='Invoiced')
       {
               tempOrderLines[i].calculated_estimated_delivery_date__c=tempShipmentLines[i].estimated_delivery_date__c;
       }
       if(tempOrderLines[i].status__c=='Shipped but not billed')
       {
           tempOrderLines[i].calculated_estimated_delivery_date__c=tempShipmentLines[i].estimated_delivery_date__c;
       }           
     if(tempShipmentLines.size()==0)
     {
         singlegroup.add( new wrapgroupwise(tempacc[i],tempOrderLines,tempShipmentLines, null));
     }
         else{
              singlegroup.add( new wrapgroupwise(tempacc[i],tempOrderLines,tempShipmentLines, tempInvoiceLines)); 
         }
      }//size check of temp shipping order  
     }
   }
  return singlegroup; 
  }
 public class wrapgroupwise
 {
    public List<order_lines__c> con {get;set;}
    public orders__c acc {get;set;}
    public List<shipment_lines__c> opp {get;set;}
    public List<invoice_lines__c> inv {get;set;}

     public wrapgroupwise( orders__c a , list<order_lines__c> c,list<shipment_lines__c> o, List<invoice_lines__c> i)
     {
        acc = a;
        con = c;
        opp = o;
        inv = i;
      } 
  } 

  }
```

And the VF

```
     <apex:page standardcontroller="orders__c" extensions="OrderTrackingList" sidebar="true" title="Order Tracking" showHeader="true">
<!--Order details-->
<apex:sectionheader title="Order" subtitle="Detail"/>
<!--   <apex:form style="align-center:center;"> -->
     <apex:pageBlock >                   
         <apex:repeat value="{!StartHere}" var="gp">                              
             <apex:pageblocksection title="Order Details" showheader="true" collapsible="true" columns="2">
                  <apex:outputText value="{!gp.acc.Orders__c}" />
                  <apex:outputText value="{!gp.acc.number_of_line_items__c}" label="Total Materials"/>
                  <apex:outputText value="{!gp.acc.customer_order_number__c}"  label="Customer PO Number"/>
                  <apex:outputText value="{!gp.acc.account__r.name}"/>
                  <apex:outputText value="{!gp.acc.CreatedDate}"/>
             </apex:pageblocksection>     

             <!--Order Line details-->

            <apex:pageblocksection title="Order Lines" showheader="true" collapsible="true" columns="1">
            <!-- rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(gp.con))}" -->        

              <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!gp.con}" var="p" border="9">          

                <apex:column colspan="7" > 
                    <apex:facet name="header">#</apex:facet>
                    <!--<apex:outputLink value="/{!p.id}"><apex:outputText value="{!p.Name}"/></apex:outputLink>-->
                    <apex:outputLink value="/{!p.id}"><apex:outputText value="{!p.Name}"/></apex:outputLink>
                </apex:column>
                 <apex:column >
                     <apex:facet name="header">Material Name</apex:facet>
                     <apex:outputText value="{!p.material_name__c}"/>
                 </apex:column>                    
                 <apex:column >
                     <apex:facet name="header">Material No.</apex:facet>
                     <apex:outputText value="{!p.material_no__c}"/>
                 </apex:column>
                 <apex:column >
                     <apex:facet name="header">Quantity</apex:facet>
                     <apex:outputText value="{!p.quantity_ordered__c}"/>
                 </apex:column>                                          
                 <apex:column >
                     <apex:facet name="header">Status</apex:facet>
                     <apex:outputText value="{!p.status__c}"/>
                 </apex:column>
                 <apex:column title="Customer Requested Delivery Date">
                     <apex:facet name="header">RDD</apex:facet>              
                      <apex:outputText value="{!IF(OR(p.material_group__c = 'K', p.material_group__c = 'KL', p.material_group__c = 'KC', p.material_group__c = 'E', p.material_group__c = 'E1', p.material_group__c = 'E2', p.material_group__c = 'E3', p.material_group__c = 'W4', p.material_group__c = 'EKC', p.material_group__c = 'EC', p.material_group__c = 'EMC') ,'Week Of {0, date, MM/d/yyyy}','{0, date, MM/d/yyyy}')}" rendered="{!gp.acc.requested_delivery_date__c!=null}">
                     <apex:param value="{!gp.acc.requested_delivery_date__c}" /> 
                    </apex:outputText>     
                 </apex:column>
                 <apex:column title="Estimated Delivery Date at time of Order">
                     <apex:facet name="header">EDD</apex:facet>              
                      <apex:outputText value="{!IF(OR(p.material_group__c = 'K', p.material_group__c = 'KL', p.material_group__c = 'KC', p.material_group__c = 'E', p.material_group__c = 'E1', p.material_group__c = 'E2', p.material_group__c = 'E3', p.material_group__c = 'W4', p.material_group__c = 'EKC', p.material_group__c = 'EC', p.material_group__c = 'EMC') ,'Week Of {0, date, MM/d/yyyy}','{0, date, MM/d/yyyy}')}" rendered="{!p.planned_ship_date__c!=null}">
                      <apex:param value="{!p.planned_ship_date__c}" />                            
                    </apex:outputText>    
                 </apex:column>  


                 <apex:column breakBefore="true" colspan="12">

             <!--Shipment Line details-->                    
                 <apex:pageblocksection title="Shipment Informations" collapsible="true" columns="1" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(gp.opp))}" >
                    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!gp.opp}" var="q" >

                          <apex:column> 
                                 <apex:facet name="header">Shipment Lines</apex:facet>
                                 <apex:outputLink value="/{!q.id}"><apex:outputText value="{!q.Name}"/></apex:outputLink>
                          </apex:column> 
                          <apex:column>
                                 <apex:facet name="header">Quantity Shipped</apex:facet>
                                 <apex:outputText value="{!q.quantity_shipped__c}"/>
                          </apex:column>  
                          <apex:column >
                               <apex:facet name="header">Carrier Name</apex:facet>
                               <apex:outputText value="{!q.Shipment_Number__r.carrrier_name__c}"/>
                          </apex:column>   
                          <apex:column >
                              <apex:facet name="header">Carrier Website</apex:facet>
                              <apex:outputLink value="{!q.Shipment_Number__r.carrier_website__c}" ><apex:outputText value="{!q.Shipment_Number__r.carrier_website__c}"/></apex:outputLink>
                          </apex:column>    
                          <apex:column >
                              <apex:facet name="header">Tracking Number</apex:facet>
                              <apex:outputText value="{!q.Shipment_Number__r.tracking_number__c}"/>
                          </apex:column>

                         <apex:column title="Estimated Delivery Date at the time of Shipment">
                              <apex:facet name="header">Est Deliv Date</apex:facet>              
                              <apex:outputText value="{!IF(OR(p.material_group__c = 'K', p.material_group__c = 'KL', p.material_group__c = 'KC', p.material_group__c = 'E', p.material_group__c = 'E1', p.material_group__c = 'E2', p.material_group__c = 'E3', p.material_group__c = 'W4', p.material_group__c = 'EKC', p.material_group__c = 'EC', p.material_group__c = 'EMC') ,'Week Of {0, date, MM/d/yyyy}','{0, date, MM/d/yyyy}')}" rendered="{!q.estimated_delivery_date__c!=null}">
                              <apex:param value="{!q.estimated_delivery_date__c}" /> 
                              </apex:outputText> 
                         </apex:column>     
                         <apex:column >
                              <apex:facet name="header" >Actual Delivery Date</apex:facet>              
                              <apex:outputText value="{!IF(OR(p.material_group__c = 'K', p.material_group__c = 'KL', p.material_group__c = 'KC', p.material_group__c = 'E', p.material_group__c = 'E1', p.material_group__c = 'E2', p.material_group__c = 'E3', p.material_group__c = 'W4', p.material_group__c = 'EKC', p.material_group__c = 'EC', p.material_group__c = 'EMC') ,'Week Of {0, date, MM/d/yyyy}','{0, date, MM/d/yyyy}')}"  rendered="{!q.Actual_Delivery_Date__c!=null}">
                              <apex:param value="{!q.Actual_Delivery_Date__c}"/> 
                              </apex:outputText> 
                         </apex:column>  
                   </apex:pageBlockTable>
                   </apex:pageblocksection>   
                   </apex:column>     

                </apex:pageBlockTable>

             </apex:pageblocksection>


         </apex:repeat>             
         </apex:pageBlock>

<!-- </apex:form>  -->
 </apex:page>
```

Any suggestion will be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The child objects need relating to the correct parent object. So if the SOQL relationship fields can't be used (because of the one level limitation), then you need to use small Apex classes to relate the objects. I think it is simplest to use the same pattern for all three levels.

So with all the detail stripped out, the controller class would be something like this:

```
public with sharing class MyController {

    public class Order {
        public Order__c sob {get; set;}
        public OrderLine[] orderLines {get; set;}
        Order(Order__c sob) {
            this.sob = sob;
            this.orderLines = new OrderLine[] {};
        }
    }

    public class OrderLine {
        public Order_Line__c sob {get; set;}
        public ShipmentLine[] shipmentLines {get; set;}
        OrderLine(Order_Line__c sob) {
            this.sob = sob;
            this.shipmentLines = new ShipmentLine[] {};
        }
    }

    public class ShipmentLine {
        public Shipment_Line__c sob {get; set;}
        ShipmentLine(Shipment_Line__c sob) {
            this.sob = sob;
        }
    }

    // Visualforce gets all data starting from here
    public Order[] orders {get; set;}

    public MyController() {
        init();
    }

    private init() {

        orders = new Order[] {};

        Map<Id, Order> ordersMap = new Map<Id, Order>();
        for (Order__c sob : [
                select ...
                from Orders__c
                where Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')
                order by ...
                ]) {
            Order w = new Order(sob);
            ordersMap.put(sob.Id, w);
            orders.add(w);
        }

        Map<Id, OrderLine> orderLinesMap = new Map<Id, OrderLine>();
        for (Order_Line__c sob : [
                select ...
                from Order_Line__c
                where Order__c in :ordersMap.keySet()
                order by ...
                ]) {
            OrderLine w = new OrderLine(sob);
            orderLinesMap.put(sob.Id, w);
            // Add child to correct parent
            ordersMap.get(sob.Order__c).orderLines.add(w);
        }

        Map<Id, ShipmentLine> shipmentLinesMap = new Map<Id, ShipmentLine>();
        for (Shipment_Line__c sob : [
                select ...
                from Shipment_Line__c
                where Order_Line__c in :orderLinesMap.keySet()
                order by ...
                ]) {
            ShipmentLine w = new ShipmentLine(sob);
            shipmentLinesMap.put(sob.Id, w);
            // Add child to correct parent
            orderLinesMap.get(sob.Order_Line__c).shipmentLines.add(w);
        }
    }
}
```

with the data accessed in the Visualforce like this:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!orders}" var="order">
    {!order.sob.Name}
    ...
    <apex:repeat value="{!order.orderLines}" var="orderLine">
        {!orderLine.sob.Name}
        ...
        <apex:repeat value="{!orderLine.shipmentLines}" var="shipmentLine">
            {!shipmentLine.sob.Name}
            ...
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: This seems to be the simplest and best way. You are a great mentor. Thanks @keith-c